# I am having trouble transferring my coin from coin-base wallet to coin-base pro

Tags: erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, coinbase, transfer

Hello guys i am trying to transfer my coin from coin-base wallet to coin-base pro. it shows me a message " you are trying to send an erc20 token which are issued on the Ethereum  blockchain. This mean you need ETH to pay the miner;s fee to send this coin. I completely do not understand that

Comment: I have the same issue, it would help if someone explained how to pay ether cost. I understand I have to pay the question is how do I pay it. I have enough in my balance to cover it.

Comment: Every single transaction can only be executed by paying a fee. Please do not use something you do not understand. Moreover, this is something you should checkout with coinbase directly.

Answer (score 1):

All transactions in the Ethereum blockchain require some Ether to pay for the transaction. So you simply need to have Ethers in your wallet to pay for the transaction (its gas costs).

Comment: but i am trying to transfer chain-link to coinbase. How do i pay for the Gas cost

Comment: As I said you need to have Ether to pay for the transaction costs (gas)